# Node.js with scheduler and multiple instances in Cloud Foundry

Tags: node.js, scheduler, cloud-foundry

I would like to have a Node.js app running in multiple instances in Cloud Foundry. 
The app has - among others - a scheduler (`"node-schedule": "^0.2.7"`) which writes a status to a mongo-db once every minute. Now with multiple instances of the app, I get multiple entries - for each instance one - in the database.
I'm looking for something to synchronize instances to ensure just one instance "gets the lock" to write to the database once every minute. I already found suggestions to use singleton frameworks or middleware but they are request-centric, not "from the inside" of the app - the scheduler.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each application instance will have an environment variable set, CF-INSTANCE-INDEX, to expose the instance index. You could make only the instance with index '0' responsible for scheduling logs entries.

http://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#CF-INSTANCE-INDEX

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately that doesn't fit my definition of a robust solution. What happens if instance 0 fails?
I ended up adding a new mongodb service. Each instance queries the db for a timestamp of the given timeinterval (e.g. the current minute). If there is no entry, the instance will create it and acts as if it got a lock with this action. the other instances will query the db too and notice that there is already an entry so they remain silent. This works pretty well, I might just need to add a `sleep` command in the future to prevent _really_ simultaneous access to the db